# file/libmagic: What is the "ID3 length"?

Tags: file-command

The [man pages](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=magic&sektion=5) of the file command/libmagic are talking about a datatype called "ID3 length".
The only explanation i found was:
`A 32-bit ID3 length`

So what is this for a type ? Is it related to the ID3-Tag in mp3s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [magic(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=magic&sektion=5) manual page says only (referring to this as a datatype):

```
  beid3   A 32-bit ID3 length in big-endian byte order.

  leid3   A 32-bit ID3 length in little-endian byte order.
```

and libmagic's associating the ID3 tags with mp3 has been noticed, e.g., [Discussion: libmagic for MP3 can go horribly wrong](http://sox-devel.narkive.com/LWTmqhMk/libmagic-for-mp3-can-go-horribly-wrong), since the feature was added in [2008](http://git.abstraction.fr/~sylvain/?p=file.git;a=commitdiff_plain;h=f6689561138adeb01de0970fc936c10f658d051d):

```
2008-11-06 18:18  Christos Zoulas <christos@zoulas.com>

    * Handle ID3 format files.
```

The [ID3 format](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure) stores the tag length as a special 32-bit integer (which is the length you are asking about):

The ID3v2 tag size is stored as a 32 bit synchsafe integer (section
   6.2), making a total of 28 effective bits (representing up to 256MB).

Further reading:

- [Why are there Synchsafe Integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223025/why-are-there-synchsafe-integer)